# Speed of atom from kinetic energy of molecule

Tags: vasp, molecular-dynamics, python, mathematical-modeling

What is the velocity of each hydrogen atom in an H2 molecule, given a kinetic energy of hydrogen molecule is 0.12 eV, when expressed in angstroms per femtosecond and assuming equal velocities for both hydrogen atoms (using in POSCAR file for initial velocity)?

Comment: You always can use the classic definition of kinetic energy: $E_k=mv^2/2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## What is the kinetic energy of a molecule?

There is not just one type of kinetic energy when we have a composite system (made up of more than one particle, as in the case of a molecule). For example, molecules have **rotational kinetic energy**, and **translational kinetic energy**. Most people are interested in translational kinetic energy first.

## Translational kinetic energy

The kinetic energy of a dinuclear molecule is often given by the following formula (assuming that the velocity is constant, otherwise we might write this expression in terms of momentum rather than velocity):

$$
\tag{1}
K = \frac{1}{2}\mu v^2,
$$

in which $\mu$ is the "reduced mass" of the molecule:

$$\tag{2}
\mu = \frac{m_1 m_2}{m_1 + m_2},
$$

in which $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the masses of the two atoms that came together to form that dinuclear molecule.

If you want the velocity of the molecule's centre of mass, you can re-arrange my Eq. 1 to find $v$. We can assume that the rigid molecule's nuclei are moving with at the same speed as the center of mass (we are ignoring any other types of motion such as vibrations and rotations), **so the hydrogen nuclei can be considered to move at the speed $v$ that you obtain from re-arranging and solving my Eq. 1.**

## Do we use atomic masses or nuclear masses?

People that do *ab initio* electronic structure calculations use nuclear masses for convenience, but spectroscopists that are concerned more with matching theory to spectroscopic experiments, often use atomic masses, because the mass of the atom is not as simple as $m_{\textrm{nucleus}} + m_{\textrm{electrons}}$: removing electrons has an effect on energy, and in special relativity, energy and mass are related. Therefore, it's better to use atomic masses, which include the entire atom (including the nucleus and all electrons and all associated energy) so that we don't have to worry about making corrections due to the effects of special relativity. **If we know the "mass" of the entire molecule, that might even be better, but usually we use the reduced mass based on my Eq. 2, and use atomic masses in the formula.**

## Conversion of units

Many people might have other preferences, but in situations with many types of units being mixed, I love to simplify things back to how I learned them in school (you might think this is tedious, but I prefer doing it this way): the energy in eV can be converted to the SI unit of Joules. Then if we use the atomic masses in kilograms when solving for $v$ in my eq. 1, we will get $v$ in m/s (meters per second). We can then use the fact that 1 metre is $10^{10}$ Angstroms, and 1 second is $10^{15}$ femtoseconds, to get the velocity in Angstroms/fs.

Comment: I appreciate the wealth of information. Thank you. I want to calculate the individual velocity of hydrogen atoms. Since the velocities of both hydrogen atoms are the same in this case, I plan to calculate the velocity using the first equation. Afterward, I intend to apply the conservation of linear momentum rule, which is given by ( mv = m1​v1​+m2​v2​) equation. My brief question is, should I use the molecular mass or the reduced mass of H2 in this equation (place of m)?

Comment: @RubiAgrawal I don't have much keyboard access on the weekdays this year, and my weekends are full because of all of my commitments which I am not able to fulfill on weekdays. I wrote this answer on a tablet while away from my office and in the middle of talking with several colleagues about an upcoming paper and also carrying or at least watching my son who has separation anxiety after his mom went to work. I was not expecting momentum to enter this problem, and your formula looks strange to me without vector symbols. I suggest you ask a question about the momentum part in a new post.

Comment: okey okey @Nike Dattani   thank you so much.